# Swift: Passing custom HTTP header while handling the basic authentication challenge via delegate

Tags: swift, urlsession

I make a network call to my web service and get a basic auth challenge.

I need to pass the username, password and a cookie in my challenge response. How can I achieve this? **Please note, I can not pass the headers as a part of the initial request as there are some server side restrictions, hence I need to respond the challenge dynamically with these headers:**

What I am using right now:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession!, task: NSURLSessionTask!, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge!, completionHandler: ((NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void)!){
    println("task-didReceiveChallenge")

    if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
        println("Alert Please check the credential")
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
    } else {
        var credential = NSURLCredential(user:"username", password:"password", persistence: .ForSession)
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential,credential)
    }
}
```

How can I pass a custom header inside the completion handler at this line?

```
completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential,credential)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but using implicitly unwrapped optionals as required input argument types seems like a really bad idea. Moreover, don't use `Foundation` data types when they have native Swift alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. It's just something I wrote off the top of my head.I am interesting in knowing is it possible to pass a custom header at this point of handling the challenge.